# How to add validations to show that the username is already exits in ASP .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually my requirement is i should validate whether the user is existing Supplier or not? If user name already exists then it should show that the Supplier name or supplier code already exits so please select another name or code.
(Note: Here i should validate both for name and code)
HERE IS MY CODE

```
     public ActionResult CreateSupplier()
    {

        var suppliers = db.Suppliers;
        ViewBag.Suppliers = suppliers;
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSupplier(Supplier supplier)
    {

      try{

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            supplier.CreatedbyUserId = Convert.ToInt32(this.Session["_SessionUserId"]);
            supplier.UpdatedbyUserId = Convert.ToInt32(this.Session["_SessionupdatedUserId"]);
            supplier.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Session["_SessionDate"]);
            db.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect("CreateSupplier");  
        }
        }

    catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw (ex);
        }
        else   
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And i used this code in Global.asax page

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userId = 1;
        int updatedUserId = 1;
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionUserId", userId);

        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionupdatedUserId", updatedUserId);

        DateTime createdDate = DateTime.Now;
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionDate", createdDate);

    }
```

My cshtml code is

```
        <div class=" col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierName, new { @class = " form-control-label", style = "font-size:15px" })
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierName, new { @class = "form-control display-inline", id = "Name" }) 
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SupplierName)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class=" col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierCode, new { @class = " form-control-label", style = "font-size:15px" })
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierCode, new { @class = "form-control display-inline", id = "Name" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierCode)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

plese help me how to slove it.

Thanks,
Kirankuamr

Comment: You should consider a `[Remote]` attribute. [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult CreateSupplier()
{

    var suppliers = db.Suppliers;
    ViewBag.Suppliers = suppliers;
    return View();

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateSupplier(Supplier supplier)
{

  try{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        supplier.CreatedbyUserId = Convert.ToInt32(this.Session["_SessionUserId"]);
        supplier.UpdatedbyUserId = Convert.ToInt32(this.Session["_SessionupdatedUserId"]);
        supplier.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Session["_SessionDate"]);
Suppliers objSup = new Suppliers();
 objSup = db.Suppliers.Where(x=>x.CreatedbyUserId ==supplier.CreatedbyUserId).FirstOrDefault();
if(objSup !=null){
        db.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("CreateSupplier");  
    }
else{
 ModelState.AddModelError("","Suplier already exists.");
    }
    }
    }

catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw (ex);
    }
    else   
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

cshtml code is

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
 <div class=" col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierName, new { @class = " form-control-label", style = "font-size:15px" })
                            </div>
                            <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierName, new { @class = "form-control display-inline", id = "Name" }) 
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SupplierName)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierCode, new { @class = " form-control-label", style = "font-size:15px" })
                            </div>
                            <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierCode, new { @class = "form-control display-inline", id = "Name" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierCode)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
}
```

Comment: Actually i am fresher so i dont have any idea. So please be specific i am getting an error showing that there is no overload method for the AddModelError.

Comment: ModelState.AddModelError("","Suplier already exists."); use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom validator for that.

```
public class ValidateUserName: ValidationAttribute
{
    string userName;
    public ValidateUserName(string userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    if (UserNameExist())
    {
        return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

And check username in SP and return bool based on that inside `UserNameExist()`. And use this attribute on your model property

```
[ValidateUserName]
public string UserName {get; set;}
```